# unable to render data in required format in mvc project

Tags: c#, c, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am doing one project in mvc. I have checkboxes for read and write and 2 ids. from form i will receive data in the below format. i will get int perm_id, read values i will get in the form of array of int for example int[] read={1345},int[]write={1235}

```
per_id     read  write
   1        1      1
   1               2
   1        3      3
   1        4      
   1        5      5

   1        7      7
```

Here permission id is same. Under read there is a value 1 that means corresponding checkbox is checked. In first column  under the write there is a value 1 so corresponding check box is checked. In second row under the right there is null so corresponding checkbox is unchecked again there is a value 2 under write so again corresponding checkbox is checked. in 6 row both checkboxes unchecked so read and write are null.  Now i want to render the above data as follows.

```
scrn_id    perm_id     read     write
   1          1        True     true
   2          1        false    true
   3          1        true     true
   4          1        true     false
   5          1        true     true
   7          1        true     true
```

This is he required format to save in database. i tried in many ways from last days but iam not able to save data in the requird format. Is there any one who can solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a good place for bitmasks:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BIT(n) (1U << (n))

int main(void)
{
    unsigned rarr[] = {1, 3, 4, 5};
    unsigned warr[] = {1, 2, 4, 5};
    unsigned r = 0;
    unsigned w = 0;
    size_t i, n;

    n = sizeof rarr / sizeof rarr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        r |= BIT(rarr[i]);
    }
    n = sizeof warr / sizeof warr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        w |= BIT(warr[i]);
    }
    printf("n read  write\n");
    for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {
        printf("%zu %-5s %-5s\n", n,
                r & BIT(n) ? "True" : "False",
                w & BIT(n) ? "True" : "False"
        );
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
n read  write
1 True  True 
2 False True 
3 True  False
4 True  True 
5 True  True
```

Comment: great logic. Can i implement same in c#?

Comment: I will get array like int[] read={1,3,4,5}  so how to write below code?  r |= BIT(1);
    r |= BIT(3);
    r |= BIT(4);
    r |= BIT(5);

Comment: Yes got it. Great logic.. Thank you very much Mr.Alter Mann

Comment: You are welcome ;) note that those 2 numbers (`r` and `w`) is what you need to save in your database to get/set permissions.

Comment: this %-5s %-5s holds r and w.  Yes i got it.

Comment: in this line  n = sizeof((rarr) / sizeof(rarr[0])); i am getting error. the type or namespace rarr could not be found. is there any other way in c#

Comment: I don't know how to get the array length in c#, but `n = 4` should work.

Comment: I didn't know that you needed the code for C# because question was tagged C, sorry I can't help you with C#, have you tried to replace `BIT(x)` with  `(1U << (x))`?

Comment: i am very sorry. i thought same logic i can apply in c# also. but you have given great logic. i think rest i can implement

Comment: @GiridharJoshi: No problem ;)